# Cannot start "explorer.exe" on remote server

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

I was working on one of our production servers. There were many windows on SSMS and BIDS open at the moment and i was executing some SQL queries and monitoring some job's status on this server. All of a sudden,the taskbar disappered. This is how my server's RDP window looks now:-

[image]
I believe now from the looks of it that explorer.exe has been closed. Hence i'm trying to restart explorer.exe on my remote server. In attempts to fix this, I followed the approach given here 
https://serverfault.com/questions/381730/how-to-restart-explorer-exe-remotely. 
I tried all approaches specified in this link.But to no avail. I feel this is a similar problem to what I am currently facing.

**Posting the question here since i dont have enough reputation on serverfault to post images.**

I need to get this server window back to how it used to be(with the start menu and stuff.
  Can someone please help me get over this debacle? All i need is to be able to call the run prompt or task manager somehow so that I can restart explorer.exe.

Comment: If you keep posting here you will never get enough reputation on SF to post your images in the future. You could just upload it to http://imgur.com or some other sharing site for the time being and link it in your post on SF.

Comment: Point taken.. will do that henceforth. But i really need to get this problem sorted fast so used this approach :(

Comment: Well the rules are the rules, and there are other sites within StackExchange that can help your sort this out. Using SO just because you have the most rep here shows that your might not deserve the rep after all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Close your connection, and re-connect. At Programs check the "Start the following program on connection" and enter "explorer.exe". That fixed it for me. Here you go for the full [tutorial](http://blog.integryst.com/webcenter-interaction/2011/06/20/run-explorer-exe-if-remote-desktop-doesnt-work/).

**Edit:**
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to log off.

Comment: Thanks a bunch butterbox! But unfortunately even this isnt working for me :(. I'm now thinking maybe the problem is something completely different. Is there any way i can remotely log off and re-log in?

Comment: For me it is Ctrl+Alt+End, edited the answere.

Comment: It could be a HKEY problem, that wont let the explorer.exe start, virus or something. Save everything and try restart that computer that host. If can you can do that.

Comment: I can't do that..... Production Server :( :(

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to get Task Manager up on a Remote Session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> as mentioned in the [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/381730/how-to-restart-explorer-exe-remotely).

You provided above. This should then allow you to click **File** > **New Task(Run)** and then launch `explorer.exe` from there.

This generally works if Explorer doesn't recover itself on a remote session.

Comment: Sorry this didnt work for me as I have already stated in the question

Answer (score 0):

Explorer.exe has crashed. This does happen, just not very often.

If you had Task Manager open you could use its File | New Task(Run) command to start a new Explorer instance. But without such a command you're rather stuck.

Does BIDS, being at its core Visual Studio, have Tools | External Tools? If yes then use this to create another entry in the tools menu to launch Explorer.